# Apply js code to multiple li tags when clicked without writing same js code for each one of them(li)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a html list:

```
<li>task 1</li>
<li>task 2</li>
<li>task 3</li>
<li>task 4</li>
<li>task n</li>
```

my goal is to apply js code (change background-color to black) on click, BUT without having to write the same js code over and over for each li since i will be having alot of li.

here is my js code so far:

```
const tasks = [document.querySelectorAll('li')];
tasks.forEach(Element => addEventListener("click", myFunc));

function myFunc(){
  //change background-color to black
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using forEach you can use e.target, however you will need to write in additional logic if you want to be able to change back to red later on.

HTML

```
<ul id="taskList">
    <li class="red" style="color:red;">Task 1</li>
    <li class="red" style="color:red;">Task 2</li>
    <li class="red" style="color:red;">Task 3</li>
    <li class="red" style="color:red;">Task 4</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
    function changeColor(el) {   
        if (el.classList.contains('red')) {
            el.style.color = "black";
        }
    }

    document.querySelector('#taskList').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        changeColor(e.target);
    });
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator on tasks to divide the elements in the array, then pass the element like argument to the function and do what you want with it.

Example:

```
const tasks = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];
tasks.forEach(element => addEventListener("click", () => myFunc(element)));

function myFunc( element ){
  //change background-color to black
  element.style.background = '#000';
}
```

And if you need the event:

```
const tasks = [...document.querySelectorAll('li')];
tasks.forEach(element => addEventListener("click", (e) => myFunc( e, element )));

function myFunc( event, element ){
  //change background-color to black
  element.style.background = '#000';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, the shortest approach would be to bind event on the `ul` element, and make changes using `event.target`.

```js
document.querySelector("ul").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var tar = event.target.classList;
    (tar.contains('change')) ? tar.remove('change') : tar.add('change');
});
```

```css
.change {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>task 1</li>
  <li>task 2</li>
  <li>task 3</li>
  <li>task 4</li>
  <li>task n</li>
</ul>
```

---

For jQuery, you can simply bind events, to `li` tag, like this :

```js
$('li').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('change');
});
```

```css
.change {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>task 1</li>
  <li>task 2</li>
  <li>task 3</li>
  <li>task 4</li>
  <li>task n</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery saves much time :)